# Writing units tests for a Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs

My controller looks like this

```
angular.module('demo').controller('demoCtrl',['$scope','$modal', function($scope, $modal){

  $scope.askForInput = function(action){

       var modalInstance = $modal.open({
         /* here i open a modal and display a form to get some input */
       });

      modalInstance.result.then(function(input){
      /* process the input here */   
  });

  };  

}
```

The part I am confused about is how do I test this code i.e test that a modal opened, a form was filled and data was received back in this controller ?

I am using jasmine and am stuck on the first line itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend testing `$modal`, but instead your `demoCtrl`, specifically that the `askForInput` does what it should do.  When you're creating your controller in your test, you can inject mock values for the `$scope` and `$modal`.  Because you're injecting the mocks, you have complete control over how they behave.

For instance, you could do something as follows:

```
// dependencies
var $scope, $modal, controller;

// test values
var modalOpenInput, modalInstance;

beforeEach(module("demo"));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    modalInstance = {
        result: {
            then: function(callback) {
                // define what to do here...
            }
        }
    };

    $modal = {
        open: function(input) {
            // by storing this you're able to later
            // confirm it's value was set
            modalOpenInput = input;
            return modalInstance;
        }
    };

    controller = $controller("demoCtrl", {
        $scope: $scope,
        $modal: $modal
    });
}));

it("should do what it's supposed to do...", function() {
    $scope.askForInput();

    // test the function works as defined...
    expect(modalOpenInput).toBeDefined();
    // etc...
});
```

Hopefully this gives you an idea on how to move forward.  You can even define multiple paths based on the input, and verify that each path works as defined.  Since you have access to the mocks, you're able to define how `$modal` and all it's functions behave.

Comment: dylants .. i didn't quiet get the gist of it. Where is "input" in the function open coming from ?

Comment: Looking at what you provided for the implementation of `$scope.askForInput`, I would assume you either hard code the input to the `$modal.open()` function or base it off some variables you have access to from within the `askForInput` function.  For the purposes of this unit test, you just want to make sure that in calling `$scope.askForInput`, certain things are passed into the `$modal.open` function.  You can verify that with the `modalOpenInput` variable I defined above.